# Global settings component with persisting state

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and I would like to implement something like a debugging component that can change data/toggles on the app that is accessible on each page, floating rather than integral to the page.

I made a POC that was integrated into one page, but I'm wanting to make it more mobile and agnostic.

How would one go about this?

I'm running a local express dev server to push mock data and initially I was specifying the mock data pushing that info with a login form push, but since refactoring I am struggling to think of how to persist the data, especially if I refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

You must save your data in `localStorage`,everytime your component start you load your data, if you havent your data load from server.
Finally you can use `useContext` to access data through all application.

- localStorage will work as cache data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- useContext to accessData: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html